# ¿Cómo leer variables globales en una función con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo tres variables para realizar la suma de ellos en una función y luego el promedio de los mismos dentro de unos `textareas`. He inicializado las variables globales, pero  según el navegador, el valor de cada uno de los `input` es inexistente, aunque yo veo lógico, que si hago el llamado de la función y las variables ya tienen su carga con los valores de los `inputs` ¿por que no funciona?.

Este es el código:

**Script**

```
   var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
   var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
   var c = document.getElementById("c").value; 


   function bienvenido(){
      alert("Bienvenido a la página");
    }

    function Sumar(){ 
       return (a+b+c);        
    }

    function promedio(){
      var prom = Sumar()/3;
         return prom;
    }

    document.getElementById("ressuma").innerHTML = Sumar();
    document.getElementById("resprom").innerHTML = promedio();
```

**HTML**

```
<body onload="bienvenido()">
        <input type="number" id="a">
        <br>
        <input type="number" id="b">
        <br>
        <input type="number" id="c">

        <br>

        <button onclick="Sumar()">Sumar</button>

        <br>

        El resultado de la suma:
        <br>
        <textarea style="resize: none;"name="" id="" cols="10" rows="5" id="ressuma" disabled></textarea>
        <br>
        El resultado del promedio:
        <br>
        <textarea style="resize: none;" name="" id="" cols="10" rows="5" id="resprom" disabled></textarea>
</body>
```

Es demasiado frustrante este error. El navegador lo marca para las tres variables:

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los valores se ejecutan unicamente cuando se carga el sitio, hare unas adecuaciones a tu script

```
<script>
   function bienvenido(){
      alert("Bienvenido a la página");
    }

    function Sumar() { 
       var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);
       var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b").value);
       var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c").value);
       var suma = a + b +c;
       var promedio = suma/3;

      document.getElementById("ressuma").innerHTML = suma;
      document.getElementById("resprom").innerHTML = promedio;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Tiene algo que ver la conversión de los números para realizar la división y mostrarlos en pantalla? No veo la diferencia ya que javascript es débilmente tipado.

Comment: Si, por ejemplo, utilizas, 1, 2 y 3, la suma sería 123 por que se están concatenando como texto.

Comment: Ah bueno, en conclusión, sin importar que tipo de input sea, al capturar los valores desde javascript se pierde su propiedad numérica desde el tag y se convierte en texto...